# Integrate javascriptspellcheck with angular 5 app

Tags: javascript, angular, spell-checking

Anyone has any luck integrating https://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/ with an Angular 5 app?

One of the installation steps is to copy the `JavaScriptSpellCheck` folder to the root folder of your website; its URL should be `/JavaScriptSpellCheck` and that's causing a range of JavaScript not found issues.

I managed to include the `JavaScriptSpellCheck` folder as assets below but because I think the library references some html files internally some files still cannot be loaded.

```
"apps": [
  {
    "name": "appname",
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "assets": [
      "app/assets",
      "favicon.ico",
      "JavaScriptSpellCheck"
    ],
  },
]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestions or helps please? This looks like the library I wanted where custom words can be added.

Comment: Manage to open the dialog. Dialog open fine in IE but in chrome it opens as a new fullscreen window instead

Comment: Also still trying to connect to the backend server to load dictionaries?

Comment: Any help with setting up the webserver backend (to load dictionaries) to connect to angular?